# WCF Ria, LINQ to Entity projection, filtering, deferred execution

Tags: .net, wcf, linq, entity-framework-4, ria

Lets say I've got the following entities

- User

  - UserID
  - UserName
  - UserNameAsLower
  - Profile (Navigation property)
- Profile

  - UserID
  - Email
  - EmailAsLower
  - Language

and I want to return a consolidated object, lets call it a UserDTO, but remove some of the fields that we don't want the user to see (AsLower stuff)

- UserDTO

  - UserID
  - UserName
  - Email
  - Language

if I write a LINQ query as follows and then apply filtering criteria on it, will it execute at that point since the filter criteria is being applied to the projected class property names?

```
public IQueryable<UserDTO> GetUsers() 
{
   IQueryable<UserDTO> users = (from u in Entities.Users select new UserDTO() { UserID = u.UserID, UserName = u.UserName, Email = u.Profile.Email, Language = u.Profile.Email });
   users = users.Where( u => u.UserName.Contains("Admin") );

   return users;
}
```

The reason I'm asking is if the database table behind it happens to be really large (millions of records), I want to make sure it doesn't try to load it into memory first.

Comment: You're actually storing both UserName and UserNameAsLower in your DB?

Comment: And yes, if you expose an IQueryable, not an IEnumerable, the service call will include the filters applied by the client up to the point of execution.

Comment: I'm using this an example, not necessarily the real code.  If you want a more complex version: take a look at the ASP.NET authentication DB tables, its got all of that and more in it spread across all sorts of table.

though the question is more of will it execute at the where or execute at serialization

1 000 000 records in table, projected to list, filtered out
OR
1 000 000 records in table, filtered out, then projected

Comment: It will execute the LINQ query with all applied filters and only serialize back the results.

Comment: Order of operations is this: client constructs IQueryable, client enumerates IQueryable, RIA turns IQueryable.Expression into GET request, server parses GET request into Expression tree and reconstructs IQueryable, server executes expression using IQueryProvider, server serializes response to client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIA will execute the LINQ query with all applied filters and only serialize back the results.

Order of operations is this: client constructs IQueryable, client enumerates IQueryable, RIA turns IQueryable.Expression into GET request, server parses GET request into Expression tree and reconstructs IQueryable, server executes expression using IQueryProvider, server serializes response to client.